# How to get the call graph of a mainchain transaction?

Tags: solidity, transactions, contract-invocation, calldata

Simple question, but I couldn't find the answer.

There are transactions like [this one](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf7ccb45ec150a3630eded4a3cc3a763c06292413f2cde8044959e9063283873a) which involve many chained contracts.

But as storage modify the functions being called and calldata doesn t specify names (but hex) it s hard to find what is being called or delegatecalled by what and where.

**I know about emulation solutions which consist of replaying the transaction however, this is not possible here as I don't know the full storage parameters of the involved contract at that block and finding it out would likely mean dtermining what was being called**.

So how to perform this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I found what I needed. https://bloxy.info/ offers to see which call what and with the function names when viewing a transaction.